# Tool for comparing files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, diff, compare, ankhsvn

I read the this [Tool for comparing files in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182730/tool-for-comparing-files-in-visual-studio) post and the recomended posts but unfortuantely it is only for VS-2008. I am wondering if there is a working tool for comparing selected files in visual studio 2010.

Ideally, select 2 files in Solution Explorer and right click and choose "Compare Selected Files"

I also have ankhSVN as my subversion program therefore cannot use

**Edit**: I have successfully selected WinMerge as my tool for Diff process, but how do i actually compare 2 files using it?

Comment: The above link "Tools for comparing files in Visual Studio" now gives a SO error:  _This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center for possible explanations why a question might be removed._

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "how do I actually compare 2 files using [WinMerge]?" It integrates seemlessly with VS IDE Compare command, also available from Windows Explorer context menu and as stand alone program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AnkhSVN is the same for VS2005, 2008 and 2010. You can use Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion User Tools to configure your diff/merge and patch tools. It will auto-detect most tools, so you only have to select them from the dropdown menu.

See also [ankhsvntips](http://ankhsvntips.net/post/1462457755/setting-up-diff-merge-tools)

**EDIT**: There's currently no option to diff 2 different files, you can only diff versions of the same file.

Comment: But how can i compare 2 files? The only way i can use it is if i got to Show Changes. How do i just compare 2 files together from within VS?

Comment: I have set up for AnkhSVN to use WinMerge without a problem.

Comment: Can it generate some sort of report of the changes in the file. The only think I don't like with what's in VS 2010 is that I can see the changes in the file but I can't export those changes to some file, which could be useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use BeyondCompare, its really good.
http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php

Comment: Is that one free or you have bought it?

Answer (score 1):

[SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/downloads.php) is great, and integrates well with VS2010 and AnkhSvn. It's [recommended in the AnkhSvn wiki](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/TasksHelp/ResolvingConflicts).

To compare 2 files just choose "Open File Diff..." from the "File" menu.

Answer (score 1):

VS IDE config instructions for WinMerge are available from Paul Bouwer's blog entry [Replace diff/merge tool in Visual Studio Team System with WinMerge](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/):

In Visual Studio under Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation > Configure User Tools, add entries for Compare and Merge using the options indicated.

Works great anywhere in VS IDE that the Compare command is available eg in Pending Changes and Changeset Details windows.

Also works great with Windows Explorer integration and as a stand alone tool.